# how to use zip function spark java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, rdd

i need to transform this partition of code of scala to java language

```
   scala> List("a", "b", "c") zip (Stream from 1)
   res1: List[(String, Int)] = List((a,1), (b,2), (c,3))
```

how can i replace (Stream from 1) in java?
help please

Comment: This won't work with RDDs even in Scala  - the zip function on RDDs needs an additional RDD to zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add an index, use rdd [zipWithIndex](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#zipWithIndex())

Comment: no i don't want to add indexes, i have a value i must start from it

Comment: You can zipWithIndex and then map over the result to  increment the number by your initial value -1 (spark will be smart enough to do both on the map task)